# How to add wildcard on text using BluePrism code stage?

Tags: c#, blueprism

I Have a file name like that "Informe_Pro_Bra-201712110918.xlsx", i can fixe name and date but hours no because it's variable. So i want using code stage of BluePrism (C#) put the last  4 caracters "HHMM" as wilcards, to get others files in this date even with different extension. What do for that?
Help Please

Answer (score 1):

For searching files you can use for that object "Utility - File Management", action: "Get files".

there are two inputs:

- Folder
- Patterns CSV

Please use Pattern:

```
"Informe_Pro_Bra-20171211*.xlsx"
```

That way you can quickly find the file that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Andrzej Kaczor ,i know that we can use that if our file is in local directory, but in my case the files are in FTP. Sorry i have forgot to tell that at first, my problem is how can  i do the search files in FTP. Because (*) it know as caracter not a wilcard, so i must use code stage. I haven't found the solution yet

Comment: So... maybe map that FTP as drive?

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows

Comment: I have map FTP as drive and try to use Get Files action of File Managment, but it isn't working. What can i do else?

Comment: that's strange as this action work for my ftp's.

How do you know that the action doesn't work? Does it throw an error? What kind of?

Does it return nothing? Can you check if it works with any folder on C:\ drive? For Pattern just use "*".

Comment: It doesn't throw an error and it doesn't return nothing, For a folder in my computer is work but for the ftp drive isn't. So i have code it using c#, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the all file in the collection and then apply the filter like

```
"FileName like 'Info_*.xlsx'"
```

You will be getting another collection with filtered one loop through it.

As we're already having the path append the FileName and generate the dynamic path like

```
[FTP_Path]&"\"&[Collection.Filename]
```